# How to return Observable with specific type?

Tags: java, android, system.reactive, rx-java2

I need to return Observable specified generic type. But after zip operator I get only Observable, without any type.

How to correct cast usual `Observable` to `Observable<T>` ? Perhaps there is some rx operator for this?

Example of code:

```
public Observable<Schedule> updateSchedules(final List<ScheduleInfo> schedulesInfo) {
    List<Observable<List<ScheduleItem>>> observables = makeScheduleTasks(schedulesInfo);
    Observable observable = Observable.zip(observables, objects -> getSchedules(schedulesInfo, objects));
    return (Observable<Schedule>)observable; //How to cast?
}


private List<Schedule> getSchedules(List<ScheduleInfo> schedulesInfo, Object[] objects) {
        if(objects.length == schedulesInfo.size()){
            List<Schedule> schedules = new ArrayList<>(schedulesInfo.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < schedulesInfo.size(); i++) {
                Object object = objects[i];
                schedules.add(new Schedule(schedulesInfo.get(i), (List<ScheduleItem>) object));
            }
            return schedules;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your are missing type information in your declaration of `observable`. What happens when you provide it?

Comment: What are the types of the two methods referenced here?

Comment: @BobDalgleish in expression "Observable<Schedule>.zip" zip operator can not be found at all

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Sorry, add following method getSchedules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide type information at the places that the compiler can use it:

```
public Observable<Schedule> updateSchedules(final List<ScheduleInfo> schedulesInfo) {
    List<Observable<List<ScheduleItem>>> observables = makeScheduleTasks(schedulesInfo);
    Observable<Schedule> observable = Observable.zip(observables, objects -> getSchedules(schedulesInfo, objects));
    return observable;
}
```

should work just fine, as long as `getSchedules()` returns a `Schedule`.